# Problems After Upgrading Visual Studio 2013 to UPDATE 2; Windows Store, Store Apps Stop Working

Tags: windows, windows-8, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-store-app

I just upgraded my **Visual Studio 2013 Update1 to Update2**, *which took long time* to finish, then suddenly, I can't start any App in the Start Screen.

Event **Windows Store** Stops suddenly.

I tried to Run an **App** from Visual Studio by Clicking on the **Local Machine** or the **Simulator**, It returns an Error:

> ERROR: Unable to activate Windows Store app: The App1.exe process
>   started, but the activation request failed with error ‘The app didn’t
>   start’

Is there any solution for this?... Please Help!

I posted the problem in this site: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/2d89c746-4c21-4a36-9b96-4b693d625d17/problems-after-upgrading-visual-studio-2013-to-update-2-windows-store-store-apps-stop-working?forum=winappswithhtml5&prof=required

**NO SUITABLE ANSWER YET**

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: try everything from here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2013/10/11/what-to-do-if-your-windows-8-modern-app-fails-to-start.aspx